# Run file in conda inside docker

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker, anaconda

I have a python code that I attempt to wrap in a docker:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
# Python 3.9.7 , Debian (use apt-get)
ENV TARGET=dev
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get install dos2unix

RUN apt-get install -y awscli
RUN conda install -y -c anaconda python=3.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN conda env create -f conda_env.yml

RUN echo "conda activate tensorflow_p36" >> ~/.bashrc

RUN pip install -r prod_requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r ./architectures/mask_rcnn/requirements.txt


RUN chmod +x aws_pipeline/set_env_vars.sh
RUN chmod +x aws_pipeline/start_gpu_aws.sh

RUN dos2unix aws_pipeline/set_env_vars.sh
RUN dos2unix aws_pipeline/start_gpu_aws.sh

RUN aws_pipeline/set_env_vars.sh $TARGET
```

Building the image works fine, running the image using the following commands works fine:

```
docker run --rm --name d4 -dit pd_v2 sh
```

My OS in windows11, when I use the docker desktop "CLI" button to enter the container, all I need to do is type "bash" and the conda environment "tensorflow_p36" is activated and I can run my code.
When I try docker exec in the following manner:

```
docker exec  d4 bash && <path_to_sh_file>
```

I get an error that the file doesn't exists.

What is missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Won't `bash && <path_to_sh_file>` enter a bash shell, successfully exit it, then try to run your sh file in a new shell? I think it would be better to put `#! /usr/bin/bash` as the top line of your sh file, and be sure the sh file has executable permissions `chmod a+x <path_to_sh_file>`